# How to print some elements in gwt

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, printing

I want to print one panel of page in GWT.

However someone said that you must use `iframe` because it has print method.

I tried this code but it does not work:

```
     HTML html=new HTML("<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>") ;....
    searchButton.setWidth("80px");
            searchButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    MyNative.printIframeContent("myframe", "onlineMap");

                }
            });
    map = new SimplePanel();
    map.getElement().setId("onlineMap");
    map.add(mapView.getMapWidget());
```

`mapView` .is an instance of a class that returns a GWT MapWidget and in this manner I want to add GWT map to iframe then use print capability of iframe to print google map

`MyNative` is a class that use GWT JSNI to call the printPage javascript function

```
function printPage(idMap,idFrame) {
    var myElement = document.getElementById(idMap);
    var iframe = document.getElementById(idFrame);
    var body = iframe.getElementsByTagName('body');
    body.innerHTML = myElement;
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
}
```

but browser can not load body of iframe.

Comment: Is it should be like 
`HTML html=new HTML("<iframe id="+myframe+"></iframe>") ;`
i Mean append string concatination with + symbol

Comment: try to put it like this
`"<iframe id=myframe></iframe>"`

Comment: when I comment this line : body.innerHTML = myElement;browse can load it

Comment: what is idMap??
please show calling of printpage!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String html = myPanel.getElement().getInnerHTML();
print(html);


public static final native void print(String html) /*-{

    top.consoleRef=$wnd.open('','_blank', "");
    top.consoleRef.document.write(html);
    top.consoleRef.print();
    top.consoleRef.document.close()

}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works, but it only print map and not thing in the map,I mean I have some marker that show path of an object but don't print that path.